# Are there 3D path planner algorithms in ROS?

Tags: ros, path, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there packages in ROS, which make 3D path planner algorithms for mobile (track) robot, without using 2D maps and 2D navigation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263588/are-there-3d-path-planner-algorithms-in-ros?/) by [baltic](https://answers.ros.org/users/30706/baltic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-06-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- [D* Lite for 2D and 3D](https://github.com/jhu-asco/dsl_gridsearch), or [different package, same idea](https://github.com/palmieri/srl_dstar_lite)
- [3d_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/3d_navigation)
- [MoveIt](http://moveit.ros.org/documentation/planners/)! and [OMPL](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/planners.html) probably have a few that are better maintained

---

Originally posted by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) with karma: 464 on 2017-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4